# Input text dissapears after uploading image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Somehow after I start typing text in the input, after uploading an image it removes itself completely. I tried adding a other way but failed.

https://jsfiddle.net/yuosb7gz/2/

```
var c = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

window.change = function(val) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
  ctx.fillText(val, 20, 40);
  ctx.save();
}
```

Comment: Your putting everything into the same canvas, it just replaces its value instead of appending anything

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind :D, I found the solution to this. Just remove ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);. So the JS code should look like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

window.change = function(val) {
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
  ctx.fillText(val, 20, 40);
  ctx.save();
}
```